# IcCube : how to deny a single or multiple measures to a role (Not the complete group)

Tags: iccube, access-rights

Using IcCube 5.2, I know how to deny access to a group of measures to a role ([IcCube Access_Rights](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/security/access_rights.php))

But, Is there a way to deny access to a part of this group of measures? One or multiple measure(s), but not all of that group...

Answer (score 0):

Current setup of permissions for [Measures] is based on measure groups only. There is no way to deny access to a part of a measure group.

You can still hide a measure using perspectives.